# Using Spinner Choose Language with Text To Speech?

Tags: android

My homework is a Text to speech app using Spinner choose Language.
but I do not know very much about this topic.

Here my code for MainActivity.java:

```
package com.detainhom6.doctext;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener{

    // Khai bao cac bien can thiet
    String chuoinhap;
    String ngonngu[] = {"English", "Japan", "Korea", "China"};
    EditText txtNhap;
    Button btnNoi;
    Toast note;
    Spinner spnn;

    //Khai bao bien text to speech
    private TextToSpeech t2p;
    private int kiemtradulieu = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // gan gia tri cho bien vua khai bao
        txtNhap = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtnhap);
        btnNoi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNoi);
        spnn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menungonngu);

        //
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ngonngu);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        spnn.setAdapter(adapter);
        spnn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ClickChonNgonNgu());

        Intent kiemtrat2pintent = new Intent();
        kiemtrat2pintent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(kiemtrat2pintent, kiemtradulieu);
        btnNoi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View mangV) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                chuoinhap = txtNhap.getText().toString();
                doc(chuoinhap);

            }

        });
    }

    // Tao Ham khi Goi Intent Acivity Result
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == kiemtradulieu){
            if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
                t2p = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent caidatt2pIntent = new Intent();
                caidatt2pIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(caidatt2pIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    // Khoi Tao Ham Doc Chuoi Da Nhap
    protected void doc(String chuoinhap2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        t2p.speak(chuoinhap2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }


    // Tao su kien khi chon item trong Spinner
    public class ClickChonNgonNgu implements OnItemSelectedListener{

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String nndachon;
            nndachon = ngonngu[position];
            if(nndachon == "English"){
                t2p.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                note = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bạn Dã Chọn English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                note.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                note.show();
            }
            if(nndachon == "Japan"){
                t2p.setLanguage(Locale.JAPAN);
                note = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bạn đã chọn Japan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                note.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                note.show();
            }
            if(nndachon == "Korea"){
                t2p.setLanguage(Locale.KOREA);
                note = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bạn đã chọn Korea", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                note.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                note.show();
            }
            if(nndachon == "China"){
                t2p.setLanguage(Locale.CHINA);
                note = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bạn đã chọn China", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                note.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                note.show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            t2p.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            Log.e("TTS INIT", "TTS Thành Công");
        }
        else if(status == TextToSpeech.ERROR)
        {
            Log.e("TTS INIT", "TTS Lỗi");
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.detainhom6.doctext.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtnote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/note1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNoi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtnhap"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtnhap"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/Button_Noi" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtnhap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtnote"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtnote"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_txt" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/menungonngu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtnhap"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtnote"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone please help me fix code if you can?
Thanks so much!

Comment: What's the problem? you have some errors?

Comment: language not chage!! only speech English :(